# LTspice inverting op amp circuit does not function at all like expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, ltspice, inverting-amplifier

I am new to LTspice and as an exercise I am building an inverting op amp. I have built this same circuit on a bread board and in every circuit and gotten the results I expected. However, in LTspice the the output voltage is always at ~1.5V no matter the resistance ratio and for most input voltages. Does anybody have an idea as to why this is? The green line is the input voltage before R1 and the blue line is the output voltage of the op amp.[image: screenshot of data and circuit diagram of inverting op amp]

Comment: It will help you a lot in the long run if you'd draw the schematic to resemble a schematic rather than a plate of spaghetti. It will also help the people trying to decipher it. It will even help yourself by providing a clearer picture.

Comment: Ctrl+R to rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your inverting amplifier circuit: -

[image]

So, as with any inverting amplifier, if you feed the input with a positive voltage, then the output has to become negative with respect to the non-inverting input voltage in order to maintain a virtual earth at the inverting input pin.

Given that your op-amp negative supply pin is 0 volts and your non-inverting input pin is also 0 volts, the op-amp **cannot fulfill this requirement**. But the op-amp does what it can and, it lowers its output voltage as far as it can go. That ideally would also mean ground but, the LF411 isn't a rail-to-rail op-amp and can only lower its output pin to a couple of volts above the negative supply pin (0 volts).

Try setting input voltage V1 to a negative value like -0.1 volts. If you do that, the LF411's output should then be +1.0 volts i.e. ten times higher but inverted. With -0.2 volts at the input, the output should be about +2.0 volts.

However, another problem with the LK411 is that the minimum supply rail for the device is recommended to be 7 volts (0 volts and 7 volts or, -3.5 volts and +3.5 volts as an example). You are operating it with only 5 volts and your spice model may throw up some oddball behaviour because of this.

As with any op-amp application, virtual or real, read the data sheet. The LF411 is not suited to low power rail voltage applications and it is not a rail-to-rail device by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you very much for the help but I'm not quite sure I followed you. Are you saying that I should have a negative voltage supply being wired to the negative supply pin? Also I tried working a bit with the voltages that you recommended but that didn't seem to make a difference in my results.

Comment: Make the positive and negative supply voltages +15 and -15 and use an input level of 1 volt and tell me what you get at the output. Experiment a bit; it's a sim; it won't burn.

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem immediately, thank you very much. If I'm not taking up too much of your time, would you mind telling me how you knew those voltage values would work? I tried a couple different standard voltages that usually work for me in other circuits but to no avail.

Comment: I just made sure that the power supplies had enough range to ensure that output voltages weren't limited by insufficient power rails @adclar10